# Wicked PDF title shows correctly locally but not on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wicked-pdf, page-title

I am having an issue that I hope someone has some knowledge about. I am using wicked_pdf to allow a user to download a report. I am running into an issue where when the pdf opens in your browser, the title is set as the index number of the pdf (e.g. 28.pdf). When I download the form, the file name is correct. However, **this issue does not happen locally**, only when the pdf is delivered by the server.

I have tried multiple things and still cannot figure this out. In my example.pdf.haml file, I am using this:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Example
    = wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "example_pdf"
  %body
  ......
```

and have tried multiple variations of that like not including the top two lines.

Here is the relevant part of my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
          format.pdf do
            render pdf: "Example",
                   title: "Example"
          end
          format.html do
......
```

If anyone has suggestions, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely the `Content-Disposition` with which your PDF is being rendered, and the browser's PDF viewer intercepting the PDF.

Try

```
render pdf: "Example", title: "Example", disposition: "attachment"
```

This will force the browser to download the file for you, in which case the filename should be set.